# Adding translation capability to Hierarchical Select

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I am trying to translate the taxonomy terms loaded by [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select). I have the [i18n module](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) installed and I have set the taxonomy vocabulary to  localize translate, but nothing happens.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: refresh strings and then you can get items term for translate

Comment: The string's have been refreshed yet no changes made to the hierarchical select drop down box text's